# Reactor Context Is Lost In WebExceptionHandler

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactor

When I either throw a RuntimeException or return a Mono.error, the execution is delegated to my WebExceptionHandler, as expected. Inside the exception handler I log an error describing the failure that has occurred. I have information in the reactor context which I am required to include in my logs ie. request id. However, whenever I log from with in the exception handler none of the keys in the context are logged. In fact when this is debugged it is apparent that the context is empty at this point.

Why is the context lost when the execution is delegated to the exception handler and is there anything I can do to ensure the context is maintained?

Comment: Not sure but I think this statement might explain it "Context simply cannot be reached outside of a continuous chain of Reactor operators, so there's no way around it. Can't the serializer be invoked from a Mono.fromCallable ?" - seen in this issue here: https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/1667

Comment: This is a workaround that worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56592040/6939011